# Qoppa pdf on device

Tags: android, eclipse, pdf, emulation, viewer

I'm using the library QoppaPdf which is very good. 
But there aren't much help on the net.
My problem is, that on Eclipse and with emulator, my pdf opens whitout issue, but when i transfer the .apk on my device and that i try , my pdf opens oddly.
I put two picture , one with emulator and other with device, to better understand my problem.

Screenshot of my emulator
[image on emulator](http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=131007023546293621.png)

Screenshot of my device
[image my device](http://www.casimages.com/img.php?i=131007023250811351.jpg)

So i don't understand why my app do it..

Thank for your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to resolve my problem ! 
After many search on the net and doc android ,
i simply add :  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in the AndroidManifest.xml .
You can put it in the  or in the .

I hope that i help other people.
Bye !

Comment: thomas ....i doing the same task, i got ExceptionIntializationError while creating new PDF Document..can you suggest me

Answer (score 1):

Regarding [gvsharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3271600/gvsharma)'s question about the ExceptionInitializationError, the answer can be found in another Stackoverflow post: [Qoppa PDF Android NullPointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30577560/qoppa-pdf-android-nullpointer).

You need to add the following code before making any calls to the qPDF Toolkit:

```
//this static allows the sdk to access font assets,
//it must be set prior to utilizing libraries
StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getAssets();
```