# Qoppa PDF Android NullPointer

Tags: android, pdf, nullpointerexception, pdf-viewer

I`m trying qoppapdf in my App and it runs into an NullPointer in the following code:

```
 PDFDocument pdf = null;
    try {
        pdf = new PDFDocument(url, null);
    } catch (PDFException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PDFPage page = pdf.getPage(0);
```

The error reads:

```
06-01 17:29:59.687  24761-24761/app W/dalvikvm﹕ Exception Ljava/lang/NullPointerException; thrown while initializing Lcom/qoppa/android/pdfProcess/PDFPage;
06-01 17:29:59.687  24761-24761/app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-01 17:29:59.687  24761-24761/app W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x413d22a0)
06-01 17:29:59.757  24761-24763/app D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 2569K, 26% free 10659K/14343K, paused 4ms+13ms, total 68ms
06-01 17:29:59.757  24761-24761/app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument$1.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfViewer.e.p.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

The url which is used as input is valid and works fine with other PDF-Viewer.
Does anyone experienced this or similar problems? Am I doing it wrong?

I would be pleased to hear from you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the following code before loading the document:

//this static allows the sdk to access font assets,
//it must be set prior to utilizing libraries
StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getAssets();